# SQL Date Time Convert

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to convert this date time (2022-01-28 06:04:48) to date (2022-01-28) in SQL. How can I do that?

Comment: Familiarise yourself with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date and share with us the datatype of the date you wish to convert if string then https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT(date, format)` function to format your date accordingly

**Example**

SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2022-01-28 06:04:48', "%Y-%m-%d") as mydate;

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it like this

```
declare @Existingdate datetime
Set @Existingdate=GETDATE()
Select CONVERT(varchar,@Existingdate,23) as [yyyy-mm-dd]
```

and also read this doc 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: Will it work for oldest days? For example 2022-01-20 10:10:20

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the `datetime` to `date` type, that will get rid of the time:

```
select cast(getutcdate() as date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a string, simply do:

```sql
SELECT DATE('2022-01-28 06:04:48');
```